# Error while running move_group.launch ( MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory )

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, This question was already asked once but was not answered as it did not have sufficient information. On running the moveit_group.launch, following is the error thrown:

```
MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: cool1000_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
Action client not connected: cool1000_gripper_controller/gripper_action
```

The code in the following link "https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam" is customized to a 7 dof arm having a different configuration from clam arm. The difference is in the sequence of joints in the arm. Here is the data in the configuration files:

cool1000.yaml

```
joint1_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint1
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 0
      init: 2048
      min: 318
      max: 3779
joint2_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint2
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 1
      init: 2048
      min: 1017
      max: 3084
    - id: 2
      reversed: true
joint3_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint3
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 3
      init: 2048
      min: 275
      max: 3796
joint4_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint4
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 4
      init: 2048
      min: 920
      max: 3186
joint5_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint5
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 5
      init: 2048
      min: 797
      max: 3304
joint6_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint6
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 6
      init: 2048
      min: 707
      max: 3281
joint7_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: joint7
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 7
      init: 2048
      min: 175
      max: 3948
gripper_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointPositionController
joint: gripper_joint
max_velocity: 0.2
motors:
    - id: 8
      init: 2048
      min: 1403
      max: 2670
```

cool1000_trajectory_controller.yaml

```
cool1000_trajectory_controller:
type: dynamixel_hardware_interface/JointTrajectoryActionController
dependencies:
    - joint1_controller
    - joint2_controller
    - joint3_controller
    - joint4_controller
    - joint5_controller
    - joint6_controller
    - joint7_controller
joint_trajectory_action_node:
    min_velocity: 0.0
    constraints:
        goal_time: 0.3  
        joint1:
            goal: 0.2
        joint2:
            goal: 0.2
        joint3:
            goal: 0.2
        joint4:
            goal: 0.2
        joint5:
            goal: 0.2
        joint6:
            goal: 0.2
        joint7:
            goal: 0.2
```

The above config files are called within a launch file having the following line in it:

```
  <!-- Start arm trajectory action controller. -->
  <rosparam file="$(find cool1000_controller)/config/cool1000_trajectory_controller.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="arm_trajectory_controller_spawner" pkg="dynamixel_hardware_interface" type="controller_spawner.py"
    args="--manager=cool1000_controller_manager
          --port=multi_joint_dummy_port
          cool1000_trajectory_controller"
    output="screen"/>
```

In the cool1000_moveit_config folder following are the values in the controllers.yaml:

```
controller_manager_ns: cool1000_controller_manager
controller_list:
  - name: cool1000_trajectory_controller
  action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
  type: FollowJointTrajectory
  default: true
  joints:
   - joint1
   - joint2
   - joint3
   - joint4
   - joint5
   - joint6
   - joint7
- name: cool1000_gripper_controller
  action_ns: gripper_action
  type: GripperCommand
  default: true
  joints:
   - gripper_joint
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208936/error-while-running-move_group.launch-(-moveitsimplecontrollermanager:-action-client-not-connected:-arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory-)/) by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22556/daan/) on 2015-05-28**:
Did you already solve the isue of the  "action client not connected" problem?
I will be very interested if you have.

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2015-05-29**:
Hi Daan, yes I have got a reason why this error is thrown and hopefully it is right. Just dint post it as I am still not sure if that solution helps.You would need to write a code for client similar to the one provided in this link: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynami

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2015-05-31**:
Hi Daan, were you able to resolve the error?

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2017-03-07**:
Would you post how you modified that dynamixel example?  I have the exact same issue and tried to use that example, with appropriate changes, but still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating a client similar to the one provided in this linked solved the issue:

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynamixelactionclient

---

Originally posted by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) with karma: 5 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexWoox](https://answers.ros.org/users/29695/alexwoox/) on 2017-03-14**:
Can you explain how did you implement that client? or what has to be changed in order to work with the robot? thank you!

**Comment by [Sphenops](https://answers.ros.org/users/7371/sphenops/) on 2017-03-15**:
Please check the flow of the code.Through the client you send the data to the server.Usually this error comes either when you do not have the server launched, or the names of the message do not match for the data to be passed from client to the server.Look for the message FollowJointTrajectoryAction

**Comment by [Soul Goumey](https://answers.ros.org/users/30230/soul-goumey/) on 2017-08-24**:
Hello!
Can you please give us more details?I have the same problem since one month and i can't solve.